# rdiff python module

Tags: python, diff, delta, backup-strategies, librsync

Is there a python module that has the functionality for computing rdiff signatures and delta differencing?

I need to perform these operations on a cross-platform application so I'll need something that will bundle into py2exe, py2app etc.

I've done a bunch of searching but I can't seem to get anything working. Pysync, rdiff-backup, librsync all come up but I've not been able to get anything working inside of python.

Answer (score 1):

`rdiff-backup` is written in Python. It appears to be using `librsync` under the covers and has a Python wrapper for it (look for `_librsyncmodule.c` in the source tree).

The following page may help to figure out how to build `librsync` on OS X and Windows: [link](http://www.17od.com/2006/10/30/windows-and-mac-backups-using-rdiff-backup).

Comment: Would I be able to distribute something using `librsync` easily over windows, mac and linux? Also not sure where you mean by source tree.